# jQuery .html() method syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So here's the full function/for-loop. I'm basically trying to grab images from Flickr and present them using Lightbox.

If you don't need all this info, just scroll down to "WHAT'S WRONG WITH THIS SYNTAX?" The jQuery .html() method that follows is giving me trouble. How does the syntax work in this instance? Thank you!

```
$.getJSON(requestURL, function(flickrResponse) {
    flickrResponse.items.forEach(function (item) {

        // create a new a element and hide it
        var $anchor = $("<a>").hide();

        // set the href attribute of the a element to connect to the same Flickr image 
        // that the img element connects to
        $anchor.attr("href", item.media.m);

        // set the data-lightbox attribute, and use "Flickr" as the value of the attribute
        $anchor.attr("data-lightbox", "Flickr");

        // create a new JQuery element to hold the image
        // but hide it so we can fade it in
        var $img = $("<img>").hide();

        // set the attribute to the url
        // contained in the response
        $img.attr("src", item.media.m);

        // WHAT'S WRONG WITH THIS SYNTAX?
        // Use the jQuery.html() method to set the img element as the innerHTML of the a element.
        $($anchor).html($img);

        // attach the img tag to the main
        // photos element and then fade it in
        $("main.photos").append($anchor);
        $anchor.fadeIn();
    });

});
```

The corresponding HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flickr App</title>
    <link href="stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="stylesheets/lightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>

    <main>
     <div class="photos">
     </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
    </footer>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/app-lightBox.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a test question. `$anchor` is already a jQuery object, it's not necessary to use the `$()` syntax around it. But does it fail if you do? What's the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @Shanimal The browser doesn't throw any errors. It just gives me a blank page. (One moment--I'm copying it over)

Comment: Hey @Zed, ***is giving me trouble*** is not descriptive enough. Give us something a little more to go with!!

Comment: @PeterKA In the HTML file I pasted above, the <div class = "photos"> is waiting to be populated by the JS script. I don't get any errors, but rather an empty page. Using the browser debugger, it looks like image URLs (in the src attribute) are being retrieved, but perhaps not displayed?

Comment: That's much better! Take a look at my answer.

Comment: @Zed, fwiw, you should accept the 'right' answer by checking its checkmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS you only forgot to take the hide "var $img".

If you change line, it should work:

```
var $img = $("<img>").hide();
```

For:

```
var $img = $("<img>");
```

And you have to change this line:

```
$("main.photos").append($anchor);
```

For:

```
$("main .photos").append($anchor);
```

OR

```
$(".photos").append($anchor);
```

I don't know if the flickrResponse is correct

Comment: Thank you! Why does there need to be a space in "main .photos"?

Answer (score 0):

Per [it's signature, `.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method accepts either  a string, or a function.

> .html( htmlString )
>   .html( function )

Either you want to construct a string(html) representation of the image or use the [`.append()` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) which accepts a `jQuery` object, like so:

```
$anchor.append( $img )
```

Comment: Does this set the **img** element as the innerHTML of the **a** element?

Comment: Yes, indeed it does.

Comment: I thought this at first, but I tried it and in fact passing the jQuery element `$img` to the `html` method has the expected result. (setting its html). Probably Bruno Costa is on the right track with his answer...

Answer (score 0):

You just made a simple mistake. here is what you need to really do:

```
$($anchor).html('img');
```